# sql server - are there any advantages to making a table out a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report connected to a sql server DB that uses complex statistical queries.
What are the disadvantages or advantages, especially in terms of speed, to converting views into tables to run in the reports.
For sql server I know that tables take up more space.

thanks

Comment: Look up materialized views if you are in MSSQL.  Otherwise you are pretty much asking 'whats the advantage to having a data warehouse'

Comment: Hi @Twelfth Before running the reports a script is run to create a reporting DB for a batch of reports. Would you recommend a materialized view?

Comment: No not really...from reading your comments here, you are kinda on the verge of creating an ETL process.  If you are running a script to create a reporting database, it shouldn't be too much of reach to include a couple scripts that create aggregate tables (basically exactly what you are asking here, turn the view statement into a create table statement and select from it as you need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disadvantages:

- occupies more spaces.
- processing time for the table to load time.

### Advantages:

- faster access

Comment: Hi @Adi T  relating to load time and faster access would you tend to use views over tables for complex calculations when using in Crystal reports

Comment: you are loading the data from views to tables again right? that is extra processing time. that context i mentioned.

Comment: before the reports are run I download a postgresql DB and create a SQL server DB. This therefore gives me the most up to date data. I then run a script to create the the reporting tables which takes about 30 seconds. Once this done then I run a batch of reports in Crystal reports. So the extra load time would be just in the updating process. From the perspective of crystal reports could I get some noticeable speed gains?

Comment: Yes you can. if the data is huge means its in crores in that case it will more time to process as well as more time takes to render the report data to display